# Type "Any?" has no subscript members (trying to update imageview in VC)

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

```
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

        animations.image = exerciseList[indexPath.row]["animations"] as? [UIImage]
}
```

I keep getting the Type "Any?" error. I understand it's because im using a dictionary to pass values to the TBC. I'm trying to return an array of UI Images that contain exercises animations. I've tried to cast exerciselist itself as [String: Any] then adding the UI Image but i was hit with another error. Anyone know were im messing up at?

The values are stored as such

Updated:

```
      if selectedIndexPath.item == 1 {
    let squatDictionary = ["name" : "Squat" , "animations" : squatAnimations] as [String : Any]

    let jSquatDic = ["name" : "Jump Squat", "animations" : jumpSquatAnimations] as [String : Any]
                animationVC.exerciseList = [squatDictionary, jSquatDic]
```

my exerciselist getting the data is declared as:

```
    var exerciseList = [[String : Any]]()
```

Comment: Why are you declaring your dictionary as `[String:Any]` when you know it is `[String:[UIImage]]`?  Change the declaration and your error will go away. Otherwise split the line up with appropriate downcasts for each step so that swift knows what you are dealing with

Comment: Show us the declaration of `exerciseList`.

Comment: Hello, exercise list is: var exerciseList = [[String : [UIImage]]]() i just edited it. I tried to change the dictionary to [String: [UIImage]] but was hit with another error "Cannot convert value of type string to expected dictionary value type 'Array<UIImage>'

Comment: @thelegendary3 No you need to set `var exerciseList = [[String : Any]]()` then it will work edit your question with more detail

Comment: Hello Nirav, sorry  about that! That's actually what i set the value to originally and it still gives me the error... all i'm trying to do is update an imageview within my VC through the didSelectMethod in UITableView. I passed the data from my CollectionView to exerciseList in dictionary format like so:    if selectedIndexPath.item == 1 {
                    let squatDictionary = ["name" : "Squat" , "animations" : squatAnimations] as [String : Any]

Comment: I have updated my question, is it still confusing?

Comment: @thelegendary3 What is `animation` is it `UIImageView`?

Comment: @NiravD yes it is! its the image view im trying to update

Comment: Then how can you set `ImageView.image` to array of `image` think that it is possible? **NO** Set only one image from array may be error is misleading one.

Comment: @NiravD I see, so how can i perform the animations when a TBC is selected? It's all in an array of type UI Image

Comment: @thelegendary3 You need to set `animationImages` with your array of `UIImage`.

Comment: @NiravD I see were you are getting it! Are you talking about UIImage.animatedImage? Can you give me a small example?

Comment: @thelegendary3 Check my solution for that.

Comment: @NiravD it works!!!! THANK U SOOO MUCH!! WOW!!!

Comment: @thelegendary3 Welcome mate :)

Comment: @niravD done!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be you are getting misleading error, the problem is you are setting `image` property of `UIImageView` with `[UIImage]` means array of `UIImage` instead of single `UIImage` object. If you want to animated multiple images with `UIImageView` then you need to use `animationImages` to animate images with `UIImageView`.

```
animation.animationImages = exerciseList[indexPath.row]["animations"] as? [UIImage]
animation.animationDuration = 0.5

//If you don't set animationRepeatCount it will animate infinitely 
//animation.animationRepeatCount = 5 //Set if you don't want to animate infinitely

//To start animation call startAnimating() on imageView
animation.startAnimating()
```